# Wordpress/PHP/Ajax Load More Posts

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have some code on my wordpress categories page, where if they click on the graphic, then more posts are loaded - in this case 15.

It works great the first time that it is pressed. However, once it is pressed again, it doesn't bring in the next set of posts (ie. the third), but brings in the 2nd.

I understand that the problem is the offset - ie. where it starts. So, the first time it is pressed, the offset should be 16, the second time 31, the third time 46 etc.

However, where I am having difficulty, is passing through this offset.

This is the js:

```
    $('#do-show-more-posts').live('click', function(){


    if( $(this).data("o-set")){
        $offset=$(this).data("o-set");
    }else
    {
        $offset=16 ; //assume this is 16 initially
    }

    var post_type = $(this).attr('post-type');
    var parent = $(this).attr('parent-id');
    var offset = $('.article').size();

    $(this).fadeTo(0,0);
    $('.load-more-posts-wrapper .loader').addClass('show');

    $.post( ajaxurl, { action: 'load_more_posts', post_type : post_type, parent : parent, offset : offset }, function(data){
        $load_more = $('.load-more-posts-wrapper');
        $load_more.find('.loader').removeClass('show');
        $load_more.find('.link').removeAttr('style');
        var load_more_button = '<div class="load-more-posts-wrapper">' + $load_more.html() + '</div>';
        $load_more.remove();

        if( data == '' || data == 'udefined' || data == 'No More Posts' || data == 'No $args array created' ){
            data = '';
            load_more_button = '<div class="load-more-posts-wrapper">There are no more posts.</div>';
            setTimeout("$('.load-more-posts-wrapper').fadeTo(1800,0)", 8000 );
        }

        $('#content').append( data );
        $('#content').append( load_more_button );
        $(this).data("o-set",$offset);
    });


});
```

This is the PHP:

```
function load_more_posts() {




if( isset($_POST['post_type']) && $_POST['post_type'] == 'publication' ){

    $args = array(
        'offset'         => $_POST['offset'],
        'orderby'        => 'post_date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'post_type'      => 'article',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'    => 'related-publication',
                'value'  => $_POST['parent'],
                'meta_compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );

} else if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && $_POST['post_type'] == 'category') {

    $args = array(
         'cat'       => $_POST['parent'],
         'offset'    => $_POST['offset'],
        'post_type' => array('post','article','publication')
     );

} else {

    // print_r($args);

}

$Query = new WP_Query( $args );
//print_r($Query);
if ( $Query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $Query->have_posts() ) {
        $Query->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop', 'xxxry');
    }

} else {
    // print_r($args);
}

exit;
}
```

I had an idea to create a session holding the value for offset, although that didn't seem to work. In addition, am not sure how I would delete it in case someone returns to that category page.

The code I used was this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['posts_start'])){
    $_POST['offset']=$_SESSION['posts_start']+15;
    $_SESSION['posts_start']=$_POST['offset'];
} else {
    $_POST['offset']=15;
    $_SESSION['posts_start']=$_POST['offset'];
}
```

I put that at the beginning of the php function. It didn't seem to register the addition of 15 if there was already a session.

Comment: What value returns alert(offset); called right after   var offset = $('.article').size(); ? After first, second and third iteration, of course.

Comment: than you have an error in here: var offset = $('.article').size();. I quess new post does not have .article class set.

Comment: Major apologies. 
I had somehow pasted the wrong JS. I have corrected it.
I also misread your comment. It returns a value of 14 each time I click it.

Comment: Just a quick note. You should [read here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) about AJAX in WP plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using offset, you could use `posts_per_page` and `paged` parameters of WP_Query args.

```
function load_more_posts() {

//...

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST['offset'],
        'paged'          => $_POST['page'],
        'orderby'        => 'post_date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'post_type'      => 'article',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'    => 'related-publication',
                'value'  => $_POST['parent'],
                'meta_compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );

//...
}
```

And in your JS:

```
//EDIT2: (global page variable
$(document).ready(function(){
//...
var page = 1; //don't redefine this variable each time you click.
$('#do-show-more-posts').live('click', function(){
    //...
    $.post( ajaxurl, { action: 'load_more_posts', post_type : post_type, parent : parent, offset : $offset, page : page++ }, function(data){
    //EDIT:  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ^
        $load_more = $('.load-more-posts-wrapper');
        $load_more.find('.loader').removeClass('show');
        $load_more.find('.link').removeAttr('style');
        var load_more_button = '<div class="load-more-posts-wrapper">' + $load_more.html() + '</div>';
        $load_more.remove();

    if( data == '' || data == 'udefined' || data == 'No More Posts' || data == 'No $args array created' ){
        data = '';
        load_more_button = '<div class="load-more-posts-wrapper">There are no more posts.</div>';
        setTimeout("$('.load-more-posts-wrapper').fadeTo(1800,0)", 8000 );
    }

    $('#content').append( data );
    $('#content').append( load_more_button );
    $(this).data("o-set",$offset);
    });
}
//...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, nothing is currently happening when I click on the button. I am getting a message:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
For the line:
    $.post( ajaxurl, { action: 'load_more_posts', post_type : post_type, parent : parent, offset : $offset, page = page++ }, function(data){

Comment: Now every time that I press it, it just shows the same posts that are already there rather than showing new posts.

Comment: Try to change `paged` parameter by 'page'

Comment: I assume you mean:
'paged'          => $_POST['page'],
should be:
'page'          => $_POST['page'],

If so, then the same thing is happening

Comment: Your javascript `var page = 1;` must be global, so page variable increment each time you click `#do-show-more-posts`

Comment: How do I do that? (BTW, your help is much appreciated)

Comment: See edit, it should be outside your `$('#do-show-more-posts').live('click')` function

Comment: Thank you. You are incredible!!! For the record, paged should be kept as in the main code above.