# WordPress Ajax Load More Post Button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I've barely started using WordPress a couple of weeks ago so I've been learning as I go and I'm trying to get an Ajax load more button going with the WordPress site I'm working on, but everything I've tried following won't function from this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress?newreg=df528cf1e5a04265ad991d4cd598447c) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630356/wordpress-php-ajax-load-more-posts) as well and I feel like my problems are stemming from me using the HTML5Blank theme. So any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just getting pointed to the right direction! Here's my custom blog template code for reference

Here is some edited code that I did by following this [guide](https://madebydenis.com/ajax-load-posts-on-wordpress/) and trying to make it work with my HTML5Blank theme `

```
<?php get_header(); $cat_id = get_query_var('cat'); ?>

<main id="main" class="custom-blog-page ajax_posts" role="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <section class="blogsidebar">
            <div class="blog-tittle">
                <h1>News &amp; Events </h1>
                <h3>articles.</h3>
            </div>
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </section>

        <section class="content">
            <div class="col-md-12 container-fluid">
                <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'         => 'custom-post-type',
                        'order'             => 'DESC',
                        'posts_per_page'    => '3'
                        );              

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            ?>
            <article>

                <div class="feature-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); /* Thumbnail */ ?></div>

                <h5><a id="custom-post-type-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >

                    <div class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="the-date"> <p>Posted on <?php the_weekday() ?> - <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></p></div>

                </a></h5>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

            </article>
            <?php if (($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count)) {
                            echo '<div class="post-item-divider"></div>';
                }
            ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

        <div id="more_posts" data-category="<?php echo esc_attr($cat_id); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Load More', 'html5blank') ?></div>


    </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

This is the code I have at the bottom of my functions.php file

```
   $ajaxurl = '';
    if( in_array('sitepress-multilingual-cms/sitepress.php',    get_option('active_plugins')) ){
    $ajaxurl .= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?lang=' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE );
} else{
    $ajaxurl .= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');
}

wp_localize_script( 'html5blank-script', 'ajax_load_post', array(
    'expand'   => __( 'expand child menu', 'html5blank' ),
    'collapse' => __( 'collapse child menu', 'html5blank' ),
    'ajaxurl'  => $ajaxurl,
    'noposts'  => esc_html__('No older posts found', 'html5blank'),
    'loadmore' => esc_html__('Load more', 'html5blank')
) );

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_html5blank_more_post_ajax', 'html5blank_more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_html5blank_more_post_ajax', 'html5blank_more_post_ajax');

if (!function_exists('html5blank_more_post_ajax')) {
    function html5blank_more_post_ajax(){

        $ppp     = (isset($_POST['ppp'])) ? $_POST['ppp'] : 3;
        $cat     = (isset($_POST['cat'])) ? $_POST['cat'] : 0;
        $offset  = (isset($_POST['offset'])) ? $_POST['offset'] : 0;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'custom-post-type',
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
            'cat'            => $cat,
            'offset'          => $offset,
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        $out = '';

        if ($loop -> have_posts()) :
            while ($loop -> have_posts()) :
                $loop -> the_post();

                $category_out = array();
                $categories = get_the_category();
                foreach ($categories as $category_one) {
                    $category_out[] ='<a href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category_one->term_id ) ).'" class="'.strtolower($category_one->name).'">' .$category_one->name.'</a>';
                }
                $category_out = implode(', ', $category_out);

                $cat_out = (!empty($categories)) ? '<span class="cat-links"><span class="screen-reader-text">'.esc_html__('Categories', 'html5blank').'</span>'.$category_out.'</span>' : '';

                $out .= '<article id="post-'. get_the_ID().'" class="'. implode(' ', get_post_class()) .'">
                            <header class="entry-header">';
                        if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ){
                            $out .= '<span class="sticky-post">'. __( 'Featured', 'html5blank' ).'</span>';
                        }
                        $out .= '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink() ).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
                    $out .= '</header>'.
                             html5wp_excerpt() . '<a class="post-thumbnail" href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 1;">'.get_the_post_thumbnail('', 'post-thumbnail', array( 'alt' => the_title_attribute (array('echo' => 0) ) ) ).'</a>';
                        $out .= '<div class="entry-content">'.get_the_content( sprintf(
                                        __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'html5blank' ),
                                        get_the_title()
                                    ) );
                        $out .= '</div>';
                        $out .= '<footer class="entry-footer">
                                <span class="byline">
                                    <span class="author vcard">'.get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 49 ).'
                                        <span class="screen-reader-text">'._x( 'Author', 'Used before post author name.', 'html5blank' ).'</span>
                                        <a class="url fn n" href="'.esc_url(get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' )).'">'.get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' ).'</a>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="posted-on">
                                    <span class="screen-reader-text">'.esc_html__('Posted On', 'html5blank').'</span>
                                    <a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink() ).'" rel="bookmark">
                                        <time class="entry-date published" datetime="'.get_the_date('c').'">'.get_the_date('F d, Y').'</time>
                                        <time class="updated" datetime="'.get_the_modified_date('c').'">'.get_the_modified_date('F d, Y').'</time>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                                '.$cat_out.'
                                <span class="comments-link">
                                    <a href="'.esc_url(get_comments_link()).'">'.esc_html__('Leave a comment', 'html5blank').'<span class="screen-reader-text">'.esc_html__(' on ', 'html5blank'). get_the_title().'</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                                <span class="edit-link">
                                    <a class="post-edit-link" href="'.esc_url(get_edit_post_link()).'">'.esc_html__('Edit', 'html5blank').'<span class="screen-reader-text"> "'.get_the_title().'"</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>';
                        $out .= '</footer>
                        </article>';

            endwhile;
        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        wp_die($out);
    }
}
```

Also I'm not sure if I should have this in my functions.php as well? Because when I do put it there I get a parse error and completely crashes my site

```
var $content = $('.ajax_posts');
var $loader = $('#more_posts');
var cat = $loader.data('category');
var ppp = 3;
var offset = $('#main').find('.post').length;

$loader.on( 'click', load_ajax_posts );

function load_ajax_posts() {
    if (!($loader.hasClass('post_loading_loader') || $loader.hasClass('post_no_more_posts'))) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: ajax_load_post.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'cat': cat,
                'ppp': ppp,
                'offset': offset,
                'action': 'html5blank_more_post_ajax'
            },
            beforeSend : function () {
                $loader.addClass('post_loading_loader').html('');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var $data = $(data);
                if ($data.length) {
                    var $newElements = $data.css({ opacity: 0 });
                    $content.append($newElements);
                    $newElements.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                    $loader.removeClass('post_loading_loader').html(ajax_load_post.loadmore);
                } else {
                    $loader.removeClass('post_loading_loader').addClass('post_no_more_posts').html(ajax_load_post.noposts);
                }
            },
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $loader.html($.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText) + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            },
        });
    }
    offset += ppp;
    return false;
}
```

I got all these off a following the guide found [here](https://madebydenis.com/ajax-load-posts-on-wordpress/) but when I click the load more button/text it won't work, nothing fires off. sorry for the incredibly long and messy post!

Comment: Please, post your found errors too for us to see. Thank you.

Comment: I just added more information on what I've been trying to get to work! any help would be wonderful.